# how to get date-picker (only month and year) and display it in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want create input fields where user can add month and year. I try with (see below), but Mozilla Firefox doesn't support.

```
<input type="month" id="start" name="start">
```

Does anyone know the alternative how can I add month and year for all browsers ?

Comment: Yeah that input type is not currently supported by Firefox, so your best bet is probably going to be to use a standard date input or make your own custom implementation of a month input with some JS.

Comment: You could use two `select` elements and a hidden input. Wrap the elements into a div, and listen `change` event on the div. In the handler set the value of the hidden input according to the selected values in the select elements.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can try

### The first method

```js
// define variables
var nativePicker = document.querySelector('.nativeDatePicker');
var fallbackPicker = document.querySelector('.fallbackDatePicker');
var fallbackLabel = document.querySelector('.fallbackLabel');

var yearSelect = document.querySelector('#year');
var monthSelect = document.querySelector('#month');

// hide fallback initially
fallbackPicker.style.display = 'none';
fallbackLabel.style.display = 'none';

// test whether a new date input falls back to a text input or not
var test = document.createElement('input');

try {
  test.type = 'month';
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.description);
}

// if it does, run the code inside the if() {} block
if(test.type === 'text') {
  // hide the native picker and show the fallback
  nativePicker.style.display = 'none';
  fallbackPicker.style.display = 'block';
  fallbackLabel.style.display = 'block';

  // populate the years dynamically
  // (the months are always the same, therefore hardcoded)
  populateYears();
}

function populateYears() {
  // get the current year as a number
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  // Make this year, and the 100 years before it available in the year <select>
  for(var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = year-i;
    yearSelect.appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="nativeDatePicker">
    <label for="month-visit">What month would you like to visit us?</label>
    <input type="month" id="month-visit" name="month-visit">
    <span class="validity"></span>
  </div>
  <p class="fallbackLabel">What month would you like to visit us?</p>
  <div class="fallbackDatePicker">
    <div>
      <span>
        <label for="month">Month:</label>
        <select id="month" name="month">
          <option selected>January</option>
          <option>February</option>
          <option>March</option>
          <option>April</option>
          <option>May</option>
          <option>June</option>
          <option>July</option>
          <option>August</option>
          <option>September</option>
          <option>October</option>
          <option>November</option>
          <option>December</option>
        </select>
      </span>
      <span>
        <label for="year">Year:</label>
        <select id="year" name="year">
        </select>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

### Or using an JS library

http://jsfiddle.net/yLjDH/

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it similar like **rgedit**.

I have two arrays, one with months and second is with years (i only used this and next two years, like below).

`[new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getFullYear() + 1,  new Date().getFullYear() + 2,]`

then i have two select tags where i used forEach for months and years and after that I made the date I needed.

```
let date = myMonth + '-' + myYear
let newDate = new Date(date)
```

After i have month and year I can find first and last day in month, what i needed.

It's not pretty, but it works :D Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The `type="month"` is supported in the following versions:

Chrome 25.0,
Edge 12.0,
Opera 10.1,
Firefox and Safari don't support the input type month

You can achieve it like this:

```
<select id="year">
    <option value="2022">2022</option>
    <option value="2023">2023</option>
...
</select>

<select id="month">
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
...
</select>
const yearSelect = document.getElementById('year');
const monthSelect = document.getElementById('month');

yearSelect.addEventListener('change', updateYear);
monthSelect.addEventListener('change', updateMonth);

function updateYear() {
    const selectedYear = yearSelect.value;
    console.log('Selected year:', selectedYear);
}

function updateMonth() {
    const selectedMonth = monthSelect.value;
    console.log('Selected month:', selectedMonth);
}
```

This is definitely not the best approach, but this is how it fits my needs for creating stock reports.

Answer (score -1):

***ANSWER***

— setDate() sets the day of the month of a date.

```
const d = new Date();
d.setDate(0);
```

— Set the day of the month in a specified date:

```
const d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
d.setDate(15);
```

— The setMonth() method sets the month of a date object. ***Note***: January is 0, February is 1, and so on.

Set the month to 4 (May):

```
const d = new Date();
d.setMonth(4);
```

— Set the month to 4 (May) and the day to 20:

```
const d = new Date();
d.setMonth(4, 20);
```

— setFullYear() sets the year of a date. setFullYear() can also set month and day.

```
const d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(2020);

const d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(2020, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't need display date. I need input field where user can choose month and year. Just like here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_month

Answer (score -1):

***ANSWER***

To set and get the input type date in dd-mm-yyyy format we will use  type attribute. The  type attribute is used to define a date picker or control field. In this attribute, you can set the range from which day-month-year to which day-month-year date can be selected from. If min and max values are not set then default min value is set to “01-01-1920” and default max value is set to “01-01-2120”.

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Get input date in dd-mm-yyyy format</h3>
    
    <label for="start"> Enter the Date: </label>
    
    <input type="date" name="begin" 
        placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" value=""
        min="1997-01-01" max="2030-12-31">
</body>
</html>
```